# How to copy data from one class to another class and restore it back in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a class `DrawingBuildingDetails` which has a subclass `Attachment` stored as a property inside `DrawingBuildingDetails` class. I am passing this class from from webform to wcf service where the service has same class structure as web form ..ie it has `DrawingBuildingDetails` class which again contains  `Attachment` class .Now the work i have to do is i have to remove all the attachement reached on webservice in order to log the request received from webform.Otherwise lot of attachments comes and logging will be difficult .after logging i have to re attach the attachments.But the issue i am facing is ,i am not able to re attach the attacments, ie became null.. The class structure is as below 
Following is the same class structure i maintained in webform and webserivce

```
foreach (DrawingBuildingDetails item in drawingDetailsObj)
    {
        item.Attachment = null;
    }
    //    //Serialize the request object into XML string
   string xmlString = SerializeObjectToXML(request);
    log(xmlString );
    request.DrawingBuildingDetails = drawingDetailsObj;
}
```

Here the problem i am facing in while reattaching the drawings like  shwon below

```
request.DrawingBuildingDetails = drawingDetailsObj;
```

the enitire  `Attachment`  inside the `DrawingBuildingDetails` became null;
Any idea behind it?? i did deep copy by using `Clone` method also,without any luck

Comment: remove `item.Attachment = null` and try 'item.Attachment = new Attachment()`

Comment: let me try it.so you meant after instantiating i have to make tat object properies to null??

Comment: You said that "Attachment"s should be cleaned. and you see then `null` because you assigned a `null` value to them. so if you assign new memory to Attachments the old values will be removed and it's still not null.

Comment: after removing i have to log the entire request object ,then reattach the attchements

Comment: You must return Acknowledge (It's Common in Client-Service apps) back to your WebForm. so each Attachment should have an Id and Visited ID's must be the output of your WCF function. (Instead of an ID) you can just add a Visited Field into your Attachment and like the previous solution back the Visited Attachments to WebForm again. by this way you can remove Visited Attachments after Logging them.

Comment: item.Attachment = new Attachment()` did th trick,thankslot

Comment: If your problem is solved, that's good. Otherwise I notice that Request and Attachment fields are not decorated as DataMember: I thought you might be serializing nothing, and getting back nothing. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=netstandard-2.0

Comment: This is just a snippet i posted ,everything i managed internally,thanks a lot for your support

Comment: simply create a new object and copy your attachment there, once u r completed logging you can reassign it to the first object.